# How can I calculate the distance between a latitude and longitude coordinate and an array of latitude and longitudes

Tags: python-3.x, coordinates, distance

I have a co-ordinate point (-62.68S,31.08E) and an array of latitudes and longitudes.

How would i calculate the distance between the coordinate and every lat/lon point in the array?

The array of latitudes and the array of longitudes are both the of size 35900 so I should get an array of distances of size 35900.

THANKS!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, what have you tried so far and what hasn't worked about it?

Comment: To what coordinate system do these points belong? Are you sure, that you have South/East values instead of North/East values for Lat/Lon?

Comment: Please, provide some code and data examples. Also, it would be good if you could specify the type of distance you are using, e.g., https://www.ques10.com/p/2923/what-are-the-different-types-of-distance-measures/

Comment: I have been trying to use haversine with the lat/lon point against the lat/lon array but i just am not too sure of how to loop this calculation over the array.